# C++ inheritance public and private?

Tags: c++, inheritance, private, public

Is it possible to inherit both or all parts of a class (other than private) in C++?

```
class A {
}
```

```
clas B : ...? { }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're asking whether you can make private members visible to derived classes, the answer is no - that's why they are private. Use `protected` members in the base class if you want derived classes to be able to access them.

Comment: @Alan: If you feel this answer has resolved your question, please click the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you could inherit private members, then all you would have to do to access something private would be to inherit items from a parent class.

Comment: That's an important part of encapsulation. The same for protected members really - if they're protected, someone just has to inherit to get access to them, so they might as well be public.  If you would never write a class with public member variables, why would you write one with protected?